# Url rewring using .htacess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can i change URL by using url rewriting with help of *.htaccess*

Below are the URL(s),

FROM:

**http://www.test.xyz.com/ab/web/pds/dispall/web/web-design**

TO:

**http://www.web.test.xyz.com/ab/web/pds/dispall/web-design**

**I want to use fifth(5th) parameter as a Sub Domain.**

Thanks!

Comment: Add more detail & be specific. eg: You want to remove second last parameter from all of your url or *web* from them ?

Comment: I dont want to remove it .I want use as a sub domain

Comment: What do you mean by 5th parameter?

Comment: No Its _last second web_.I want to use as a subdomain

Comment: Can I Put condition that third parameter is "pds" then I proceed for your given code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /pds/
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/.*$ http://www.$1.test.xyz.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I want little bit for help.I want to use this code only when "pds" is availabe in url as a contoller.Can you help me about this ?